# after axios get my setState hooks doesn't run

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have a lot of functions like this, using the same approach, and they all run fine.
But this one is going me crazy.

My code is:

```
    const [match,setMatch] = useState(null);

      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
            status = res.data; 
            setMatch(res.data)});

    const test = match;
```

If I debug the program and break at `setMatch(status)`, the content of `res.data` is correct:
res.data is an array, and each element contains a mix of values and objects as show in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

But when I execute the `setMatch(status)` the result is that the `match` state variable doesn't change: it remains `null` as set the first time.

Can someone provide some suggestion?

Comment: Where do you examine the value of `match` after setting it?

Comment: you mean during debugging?  `setMatch` is asynchronious, so it won't be called instantly

Comment: I changed the code, adding a new line where I breakpoint to. in `const test = match;` match is null.
But the data to fill it where present in the debugger.
In the code, I examined it in the debugger.

Comment: Make sure to run ajax calls in `useEffect` otherwise they will happen every render.

Comment: Is it inside a useEffect with a data dependecies?

Comment: No, there is no useEffect

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I dont know what could likely affect your code from running. But this is the common pattern when handling asynchronous request.
It is expected that it should be executed in the useEffect hook right after it is painted

```
const Component = () => {
    const [match,setMatch] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
       axios.get(path)
          .then((res) => {
            status = res.data; 
            setMatch([match, ...res.data])})
          .catch((err) => handleError(err));
    }, [path]) // assuming that the path changes otherwise  if you are running this once, leave the array empty
     
return (<div> {(match.length > 0)? 'Loading': {renderYourLogicHere} </div>)
}
```

Comment: inside `.then` there is `status = res.data` which is deprecated. Why not only `.then((res) => {setData(res.data)});`?